# Как обойти блокировку веб-сайтов? Python URLLib

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, urllib, web-scraping

Почему при исполнении, код, указанный ниже, выдает ошибку?

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import *
from urllib import *

proxy = ProxyHandler({"https": "https://101.71.40.163:3128"})
opener = build_opener(proxy)
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0')]

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

install_opener(opener)

class connection():
    def scrapData():
        url = "https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1693684/1.jpg" # не обращайте внимания
        destination = "lol.jpg"
        return urlretrieve(url, destination)

connection.scrapData()
```

код выводит следующее:
`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение>` я совершенно не понимаю, вроде юзер-агента я сменил, прокси подрубил, на другие заблокированные РКН сайты оно заходит (через прокси естественно). почему оно не хочет скачивать картинку? я уже все прокси перепробовал

так-же принимаются ответы, детально объясняющие работу с Tor Stem, (если оно поможет мне в этом) ибо я не разобрался, как с ней работать. (на том-же примере, если что-то решается таким-же птуем, это проблема сайта)

Comment: с таким юзер агентом я бы тоже разрывал соединение. Но может сайт придирчив и хочет, что бы и куки приложили правильные.

Comment: @kovadim Эххх. я сменил юзерагента на своего настоящего. я приложил куки, по которым захожу на сайт. я приложил другие данные - безрезультатно

Comment: значит сайт знает о Вас больше. К примеру, он может использовать javascript код, что бы подтвердить, что это не бот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я нашел ответ. нужна либа [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)
там и документация к ней есть

upd. сама проблема заключалась в наличии защиты от ботов и DDoS атак - CloudFlare

upd2. можно так-же использовать другую либу [cfscrape](https://pypi.org/project/cfscrape/)

upd3. да, кстати. нужно устанавлвать пользовательский форк cfscrape.
ссылку не дам, найдете

```
    import cloudscraper

    scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

    scraper.get(url, proxies = {"https": "https://101.71.40.163:3128"})
```

надеюсь кому-то помогло